# Haskell - Infer the type in constructor

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I'm a newbie in the Haskell's world, so this may be a basic question.

Could this code:

```
data Numero =
  Integer Integer |
  Rational Rational |
  Double Double
  deriving (Show)
data Elemento =
  Numero Numero |
  Incognita String
  deriving (Show)

data Monomio = Monomio {base :: Elemento, exp :: Numero} deriving(Show)

main = print (Monomio (Numero (Integer 15)) (Integer 20))
```

be expressed without the explicit types at:

```
(Monomio (Numero (Integer 15)) (Integer 20))
```

?

This expression:

```
main = print (Monomio (Integer 15) (Integer 20))
```

which is shorter is not ambiguous, as (Integer 15) can't fit the definition of (Incognita String), but it doesn't compile:

```
main.hs:13:24:
    Couldn't match expected type `Elemento' with actual type `Numero'
    In the first argument of `Monomio', namely `(Integer 15)'
    In the first argument of `print', namely
      `(Monomio (Integer 15) (Integer 20))'
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Numero` in the expression

```
(Monomio (Numero (Integer 15)) (Integer 20))
```

is not a type - but a <strike>type</strike> value constructor, so you need it in order to construct <strike>something</strike> a value of type `Elemento`.

One way would be to use [`fromIntegral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) in order to achieve "automatic" conversion.

For the `String`-like you have the `OverloadedStrings`-Language extension but for numeric types there is nothing like that (at least to my knowledge).

On a side note: I think it makes your code much more confusing that you have a type of `Numero` and a type-constructor of `Numero` where the latter is constructs something of type `Elemento`.

I would use `NumElemento` and `VarElemento` or something the like.

---

A more concise but completely different approach (as written in my comment), would be to use polynomials instead of monomes.

```
data Polynomial1 = P1 String [Rational]
newtype Polynomial  = P [Polynomial1]
```

here would `P1 "X" [1,2,3]` stand for `p(x) = 1 + 2*x + 3*x²` and `P [P1 "X" [1,2], P1 "Y" [0,1]]` stand for `p(x,y) = 1 + 2*x + y`

This approach solves many problems that occur, and if you are careful you can even represent taylor series (save you're not checking wether youre not checking `cosine == cosine` - though obviously true, you happen to run in an infinite comparison process).

Comment: I can see `instance Num Numero where fromInteger = Integer; […]`, but how would you create an instance for `Elemento`?

Comment: *I would use NumElemento and VarElemento or something the like.* Do you mean to concatenate `Incognita String` to **Numero** constructors?

Comment: I meant I woud use `NumElemento` in order to indicate that I construct something of type `Elemento`,  `VarElemento` for variable - what you call `Incognita`.

Comment: @Bergi I have not given it a thorough thought what to do for the Num instance - but `instance Num Elemento where fromInteger = Numero . fromInteger`  would be my choice

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, you can hardly define sensible implementations for the other `Num` methods on `Incognita` values.

Comment: If you give it a more thourogh thought I would use something like `Rational` as a base and then implement Polynomials as newtype of List of Coefficients + a variable name then you have a polynomial ring over a field (rationals) - which has tons of nice properties

Comment: In that expression, `Numero` is not a type constructor, it is a value constructor. Type constructors construct, well, types, e.g. `Maybe`,`[]`,`Either`,`(,)`, etc. Value constructors instead build values e.g. `Just`,`(:)`,`Left`,`(,)`, etc. Some of them happen to have the same name, but live in different namespaces.

Comment: @chi thanks for pointing this out - it seems that I have mixed those two terms up for at least 6 years when talking about them.